# User uploads image from web form

Tags: html, forms, google-sheets, file-upload

I'm creating a simple feedback form, I used [a tutorial](https://blog.h-educate.com/how-to-send-an-email-in-a-static-html-page-using-google-sheets-scripts/) on how to transfer all the information based on user input in the form to an email. I achieved it, but now I'm facing another problem. I want to make it that they could upload an image to it.

My HTML:

```
<input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
```

> Name: Jonas LastName: Someone ... FileToUpload: Main logo.jpg

So the problem is that it sends a file name instead of sending the actual image

Comment: Sorry for my poor english.

I meant that instead of getting from a user his photo name i need the actual image tho. 
How to achieve it?

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/file. "A file input's value attribute contains a DOMString that represents the path to the selected file(s)."

Comment: @isherwood It's google sheets generated script. To be more clear i added a tutorial i followed. But it gets only the file name

Comment: Then you certainly need to tag that and make it more clear in your question.

Comment: https://github.com/dwyl/learn-to-send-email-via-google-script-html-no-server
This is the original tutorial

So i need to tweak the script  if i want photos to get uploaded ?

Comment: @KostasSkutulas add the code you are using for your question, not the tutorial you are following. Please see [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @KostasSkutulas show your `doPost()` function. It is with that function that you should process the url and embedd it into your email.

Answer (score 0):

When the form is sent, the selected file is transferred to the server, but is only saved in a temporary directory. It is discarded again at the end of the request. A script (PHP, Perl, JSP ...) is required on the server side in order to permanently store the file in another directory on the server after the upload.